# Red shield with number in Nike+ iOS app?

Tags: applications

I'm new to the Nike + run app for iPhone. On my activity list, what does the red shield with the number in it mean?

Answer (score 1):

The red shield indicates that you broke your personal record for one of the half dozen or so records the app automatically keeps track of, like “Fastest 5K Run” or longest run. A number badge indicates that you broke more than one record in that run. (One often breaks longest and furthest run records at the same time, for instance.) So, nice run!

Comment: Thanks ChristopherE. Is there a way to find out which personal record(s) I broke? Do I have to sign up for more info like that?

Comment: If you tap on the information bar for that run, the app will bring up a detailed-information page with a map. On the right side of the map is another little shield. Tap on that to bring up information about the record.